# Webmin+dhcp server, domain resolving problem

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, dns, dhcp

Im trying to make a router from Lubuntu pc. I have a 2 NICs, one is connected to ISP and second for Lan. Im following by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXX5gCi0uTo&t=3037s) tutorial. Dhcp server is working fine, I get ip addresses, I can ping external IP, but I have problem with domain resolving. No one domain is pinging or accessible. What have I missed?
P.S. All my network parameters I get from my ISP by dhcp. I havent bind-dns server and I don`t need it. 
On pc which acts as router, everything works fine.  Problem with dns forwarding to Lan pc.

All my testings I do on windows-lan desktop
**ipconfig /all** shows:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.org
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-D4-35-43-53-4B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.100(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, March 18, 2017 09:01:34
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, March 18, 2017 09:16:34
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

sudo leafpad **/etc/network/interfaces** - ON MY **ROUTER-PC SIDE**. Commented gateway cause of Ive tried both with it and without, by default webmin didnt create it.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo enp2s0 enp3s0
iface lo inet loopback


#WAN
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp

#LAN
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 10.1.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.10.255
    network 10.1.10.0
    #gateway 10.1.10.1
    dns-nameservers 10.1.10.1 78.158.0.65
    dns-domain 10.1.10.1
```

Comment: Is the issue with external DNS names such as www.google.com not resolving? if yes, try setting your gateway on your internal machines to your pc router ip address.leave the dns-nameservers blank, or specify the router pc ip address.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial precisely. The problem is related to resolving domain names such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) properly from your lan side devices.

First, depending if internal machines are linux desktops, review the settings in network manager. Otherwise, if CLI devices, review the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

It may look something like the following:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.85.220
        mask 255.255.255.0
        gateway {ipofpcrouter}
        dns-nameservers {ipofpcrouter}
```

Verify the dns-nameservers are pointing to the correct address, in your case the address of your pcrouter.

To verify the ip address of the router, drop to a terminal on that device and issue command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Which should provide results as such, verify your mask is set correctly.

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:16:2d:5d:63:7e
      inet addr:192.168.85.210  Bcast:192.168.85.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ae16:2dff:fe5d:637e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:253666 (253.6 KB)  TX bytes:37170 (37.1 KB)
```

If the values do not match, modify the values on the client device to match. 
You may either issue ifdown/ifup to restart the interfaces, or disable/renable network manager, through the gui. Or what I prefer to do, restart the system.

For Network Manager: Check the IPv4 tab, and review the settings as described above.

Good Luck.

Comment: Lan-machine is windows, is there could be problem?

Comment: Check your IP configuration for your win station. Drop to a command prompt, issue `ipconfig -a' , review the settings, check your gateway settings, if not accurate fix, if accurate, issue `ipconfig /release' and 'ipconfig /renew'.

Comment: I have reinstalled it from scratch, now I cannot access any web, but I see that domains are resolving: ping google.com

Pinging google.com [195.122.30.45] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: I dont know, but after iptables set up again, everything is working. I was pretty sure that iptables not necessarily if I allow all packets to flow. But anyway thx.